# Syntax: derived type, nested generics

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, syntax, nested

I want to have a dictionary that maps from one generic type `K<T>` to another generic type `V<T>`. Note that type `T` should be the same in both cases. So I thought I would create a derived class from `Dictionary<K,V>` with one more type argument, but I cannot find the right syntax.

This is what I tried:

1.

```
class MyDictionary<T,K,V> : Dictionary<K<T>,V<T>> { ... }
// syntax error: The type parameter K cannot be used with type arguments.
//               (same with V)
```

2.

```
class MyDictionary<T,K<T>,V<T>> : Dictionary<K,V> { ... }
// many syntax errors: "," expected; "{" expected; ...
```

3.

```
class MyDictionary<T,K,V> : Dictionary<K,V> { ... }
// works, but does not make the connection between K and T and between V and T
```

Maybe I can use some where clause?

---

Some examples for better understanding:

`MyDictionary<int,List,HashSet>` should essentially be `Dictionary<List<int>,HashSet<int>>`.

`MyDictionary<float,Queue,Stack>` should essentially be `Dictionary<Queue<float>, Stack<float>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [generic type constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint); based on your examples you might want to settle on some base class/interface for the two. For example, the following would work for both of your cases:

```
class MyDictionary<T,K,V> : Dictionary<K,V>
    where K : IEnumerable<T>
    where V : IEnumerable<T>
```

If that's not viable, i.e. you need to be able to store mappings between, say, `Action<String>` and `IEqualityComparer<String>`, you won't be able to do that directly; you can at best settle for checking generic type parameters at runtime (e.g. in your the constructor for your class).

Comment: Your K's are different types. So are your V's.

Comment: @Dennis_E No, one of my "K's" is a type, the other is a generic type parameter. So are my "V's". Please refer to the original question, before edits.

Comment: "No, one of my "K's" is a type, the other is a generic type parameter." That's what I meant. You used K and V for 2 different things, which was horrible. But -1 removed because of the edit.

Comment: Please remove your first code segment (before "EDIT"), as this gives a syntax error ("The type parameter 'K' cannot be used with type arguments").

Answer (score -1):

Seems you need something like this:

```
class ClassK<T> { }
class ClassV<T> { }
class MyComplexDictionary<T> : Dictionary<K<T>, V<T>> { }
```

It will prevent you from adding incorrectly typed instances of K<> and V in compile time.

```
    var a = new MyComplexDictionary<string>();
    a.Add(new ClassK<string>(), new ClassV<string>()); //works
    a.Add(new ClassK<int>(), new ClassV<string>()); // compilation error
```

Comment: I have covered `class MyComplexDictionary<T> : Dictionary<K<T>, V<T>> { }` already in my question, and it does not work. It gives a syntax error.

Comment: Not sure why it gives you a syntax error, but I have checked it by creating a simple console app in VS 2017 before posting my answer. And it has worked out with no problems as expected.